# Flutter: package com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I met a problem where when I build the application, it shows there is error where the package is not exists. I am using the example code that provided at pub dev of the dependency `flutter_secure_storage`. I have already change the `minSdkVersion` to 18.

Can I know is there any ways to fix this problem?

```
android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:16: error: package com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage does not exist
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage.FlutterSecureStoragePlugin());
                                                                         ^
1 error
```

My `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-MY)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (6 days ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • COR L29 (mobile) • XTX7N18B29009354 • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77
    • Edge (web)       • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.51
```

Comment: try this `flutter build apk --release --no-shrink` with the version of my application that uses `FlutterSecureStorage`

Comment: i tried what you say but it still show the error package does not exist

Comment: which app are you building? is it android/web/ios?.. provide mainfest file also

Comment: Hi, I'm building an android app and now I already solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

after some search through Google, I have found a solution for my issue through Github. It could be some problem in the pub-cache folder. I follow the comment from one post in Github and deleted `flutter_secure_storage` inside the pub-cache folder and reinstall and it won't show the error anymore.

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/127#issuecomment-522273569